# How to change int into int64?

Tags: go

Im trying to convert an integer into an integer64 in go but im having no luck. Anyone know an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you showed your code sample why it does not work.
It works for me. http://play.golang.org/p/63GWAs8XAq

Answer (score 221, accepted):

This is called [type conversion](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#conversions) :

```
i := 23
var i64 int64
i64 = int64(i)
```

Comment: I was doing (int64)i, it din't work, old habit from clang. This reverse from C++ worked.

Answer (score 31):

This is probably obvious, but simplest:

```
i64 := int64(23)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
i := 23
i64 := int64(i)
fmt.Printf("%T %T", i, i64) // to print the data types of i and i64
```

Comment: is it possible to use `LL` as postfix like c/c++?